# Would the Catholic Church have problems with gays or lesbians getting married under state law but not having sex?

Tags: catholicism, catholic-catechism, same-sex-marriage

I know that the Catholic Church is against gays or lesbians having sex.

But has the Catholic Church said anything about a hypothetical or actual situation of gay or lesbian Catholics getting married under state law, going on dates, kissing, raising children but not having sex? Would the Catholic Church have any problems with that? If so, what?

Comment: Again, **slow down** on the questions. They are not exactly *bad*, but you *are* kinda taking over the front page. Be patient, get answers to the questions you've already asked, then ask more.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman What's the max no of questions per unit time here?

Comment: I don't know what the system's rate limit would be, but I suggest that 1-3 questions a day is enough.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman Okay thanks but should I assume that you were unaware that other stackexchange sites have a max no of 6 a day?

Comment: Indeed, I was unaware of that, but their policies are not ours. In any case, 6 questions over the course of one day is different from six questions within an hour, which you kinda did. (And 6 questions in one day a bit much.)

Comment: @El'endiaStarman Thanks for informing me :)

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, there would be problems with that**.

The Church views "openness to having children [biological children of one's own, i.e. children conceived by the woman and the man]" as a vital part of marriage:

> The marriage covenant, by which a man and a woman form with each other an intimate communion of life and love, has been founded and endowed with its own special laws by the Creator. By its very nature it is ordered to the good of the couple, **as well as to the generation and education of children**.

(This does not mean that if a couple, wanting children, discover after the wedding that they are infertile, their marriage is *ipso facto* invalid. The willingness and desire to have children of one's own is the key here.)

Homosexuals, however, are of their very nature unable to have biological children of their own (that is, with genetic material of both parents) produced by a natural sexual act. For this reason, a relationship between them is unable to be classified by the Church as a "marriage" as the Catholic Church defines the term.

The fact that the relationship is legalized by an act of the State, not the Church, makes no difference; some in the Church have argued that having the State be the entity that recognizes and regulates marriage actually confuses the issue. Marriage is a relationship instituted by God; and having a relationship which is called "marriage" but is not is at best confusing, and at worst scandalous (i.e. tending to promote sinful activity).

Thus, **the Church would say that such a relationship as you describe is not an actual marriage, and the couple involved may harm themselves and perhaps others by pretending to be what they in fact are not**.

Comment: I'm really sorry. I think I was unclear in my intention. When I said "problems" I meant to ask if those gay Catholics are committing sins of any kind or are banned from getting communion or things of that sort. Of course the Church does not recognize them as a married couple, but they are in a committed relationship, living together, raising children and not having sex (but kissing). Is there any sin committed? I apologize for giving the impression that I was asking if they could ever get married in Church

Comment: So Matt Gutting, about the last paragraph, in what manner might the gay or lesbian couple involved harm themselves or others? In what manner is the gay or lesbian couple living in pretense?

Comment: Hm. OK. The answer would still be "yes, the Church would have problems with it," but I'll clarify my answer to flu) focus on that. It'll be tomorrow though.

Comment: What is "flu)" ?

Comment: A typo. (I'm on my phone right now.) Ignore it.